# My sql query Meaning of star ( * )

Tags: mysql

I have one query -

```
(`mg_profesional_category`.`pc_active` * `mg_activity`.`ac_active`) AS `pc_active`
```

In this query what is the meaning of star ( `*` ).

My Complete query -

```
select `mg_profesional_category`.`pc_code` AS `pc_code`,
 `mg_profesional_category`.`pc_pt_code` AS `pc_pt_code`, 
 `mg_profesional_category`.`pc_code` AS `pc_pc_code`,
  NULL AS `pc_sp_code`, 
  `mg_profesional_category_language`.`pl_name` AS `pc_name`,
   `mg_profesional_category_language`.`pl_ln_code` AS `pc_ln_code`, 
   'profesional' AS `pc_type`, 
   (`mg_profesional_category`.`pc_active` * `mg_activity`.`ac_active`) AS `pc_active`,
    `mg_profesional_category`.`pc_delete` AS `pc_delete` from
     (((`mg_profesional_category` join `mg_profesional_category_language` on((`mg_profesional_category`.`pc_code` = `mg_profesional_category_language`.`pl_pc_code`)))
      left join `mg_specialties` on((`mg_profesional_category`.`pc_code` = `mg_specialties`.`sp_pc_code`))) join `mg_activity` on((`mg_activity`.`ac_pc_code` = `mg_profesional_category`.`pc_code`))) where isnull(`mg_specialties`.`sp_code`)
```

Comment: `4*5 = 20 ` * stands for multiply here.

Comment: it is for production! ;)

Comment: will you please post your complete query. as @abhik said it denote here multiply.

Comment: I post my full query please check now.

Comment: @PatelPragnesh It's multiplication: `(mg_profesional_category.pc_active * mg_activity.ac_active) AS pc_active` is the same as `(1 * 1) AS pc_active` or `(0 * 1) AS pc_active` or `(1 * 0) AS pc_active`. My guess is that it's a simple "if `pc_active` is `>= 1` and `ac_active` is `>= 1`, then return `>= 1`, else return `0`".

Comment: So to reiterate, it checks if `mg_profesional_category.pc_active` is more than or equal to `1` **and** `mg_activity.ac_active` is more than or equal to `1`.